# Firestore Query Date Ranges Stored in Array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building the backend of an application that allows users to store events that can span over multiple days. Each day has a specific time the event closes and reopens on the next day. I am using Cloud Firestore to store the events data.

My users need to be able to find the events that have not started yet or are currently active.

I would like to store each event's timeframes in an array of objects that have a start and end timestamp like below. However, I cannot find a way to query this data structure for the events that happen after a given day. Looking at the Firestore docs led me to the array-contains method, but that is looking for a specific value. How would I alter the array-contains to instead look for anything after a certain value?

```
[
   {Start: (1st day start), End: (1st day end)},
   {Start: (2nd day start), End: (2nd day end)},
]
```

Can anyone help me query for future events using this structure or if there isn't a way to  create this query, suggest a different structure that will allow it?

Comment: Have you tried to use `startAt` and `endAt` functions?

Comment: @AlexMamo, aren't those used for paginating data? How would I apply them to an array of objects? I am new to Firestore so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not only for pagination, those methods are used to get data that exist within some limits.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use startAt with an array? I have not been able to find any examples.